# Flex 4.6 check if creationComplete has occured

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, events, flex4

Within AS3, I know I can check if the stage is accessible to, say, an externally loaded SWF by including this at the beginning of the loaded SWF:

```
if (stage) {
  this.init();
} else {
  addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
}
```

The above solution is great for checking if the stage is accessible to the program by the time these lines are executed, or adding an event listener to listen for when the stage is accessible.

I am trying to replicate a similar situation within a custom component in Flex 4.6. However, instead of listening for the presence of the stage, I am looking for whether or not the `creationComplete` event for the component has been fired.

Is there a similar solution for whether or not the `creationComplete` event has been fired, and listen for it if it hasn't been?

Comment: Have you looked into the [Flex Component Lifecycle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html#WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7ffc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just Windows grepped 4.6 source and UIComponent dispatches creation complete event when initialized is set to true so http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#initialized should work.

**EDIT**
In response to the comment initialize is called but set initialized to true doesn't occur at step 9 it's literally where the CREATION_COMPLETE is dispatched within UIComponent see this snippet I pulled from the 4.6 source of UIComponent:

```
/**
     *  A flag that determines if an object has been through all three phases
     *  of layout: commitment, measurement, and layout (provided that any were required).
     *  
     *  @langversion 3.0
     *  @playerversion Flash 9
     *  @playerversion AIR 1.1
     *  @productversion Flex 3
     */

/**
 *  @private
 */

public function set initialized(value:Boolean):void
{
    _initialized = value;

    if (value)
    {
        setVisible(_visible, true);
        dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE));
    }
}
```

If you don't believe me hit Ctrl+Shift+T type in UIComponent and search for "Variables: Creation" you'll get a comment block that starts the section where the start-up events are dispatched and some variables for flagging those events being complete are set.  INITIALIZE event happens in a different setter below the one I referenced.

```
public function set processedDescriptors(value:Boolean):void
{
    _processedDescriptors = value;

    if (value)
        dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.INITIALIZE));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but the reference you used is part of Flex 3. The [Flex 4.6 component lifecycle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html#WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7ffc) shows that initialization occurs in step 9, but `creationComplete` isn't dispatched until step 14.b. That being said, I'm pretty sure `initialized` won't quite cut it for my scenario. Thank you, though!

Comment: Thanks for checking back, please let me know if this turns out to be problematic for any reason as I've had to do this myself in the past too and always felt there should be something provided to know if these events have already been fired, and this is useful info for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a creationComplete event listener to your component and do the logic in the handler function? also, you could try making a single boolean property, something like

```
public var isInitialized:Boolean = false;

function creationCompleteHandler(e:Event):void
{
   isInitialized = true;
   //code here
}
```

That way you could check from external sources if it's been initialized or not.

Comment: I know I could do that, but it always seemed like the "easy" way around a problem. I just wondered if there was another way that Flex provided to check conditions such as these. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Well I can't think of any other things.. It's always a good thing to know an 'easy' way around though :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use applicationComplete instead of creationComplete since applicationComplete is the last stage in the cycle when checking to see if the stage is accessible?  I would imagine every application component's creationComplete would have to fire before applicationComplete.  Are you trying to access creationComplete before the application is ready for some reason?

I was just going back through this, and I'm not at all certain why you're actively seeking a more difficult solution.  This solution should work, and personally I feel like it's the right one.  Sure you could check to see if a creationComplete has fired, but unless you explicitly need this functionality, I fail to see the point of checking for creationComplete when you can certainly utilize a good separation of logic by taking advantage of the life cycle...